# How to achieve this in Jquery? (JS to Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

I am using Javascript to design my website, however, I am been told that Jquery is much better and can help shorten my code. I am converted most of my code into Jquery, however, I little confused as to how I can achieve this in Jquery:

```
var Buttons = getElementsByTagName("Button");
for (var i = 0; i < Buttons.length; i++) {
    Buttons[i].style.background = "#000;
    Buttons[i].style.color = '#fff';
    Buttons[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';

    Buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(evt) {

        // Do something
    }

}
```

I know for these:

```
Buttons[i].style.background = "#000;
Buttons[i].style.color = '#fff';
Buttons[i].style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

I can do something like this, not sure if this is correct though:

```
 Buttons[i].css("background", "#000");
 Buttons[i].css("color", "#fff");
 Buttons[i].css("font-weight","Bold");
```

Any help is welcomed.

EDITED:

If you have any other tips for me, please let me know as I am a beginner and can do we all the help I can get :)

Comment: At the beginning you really should learn plain JavaScript and not a framework. This gives you a better understanding what problems you can solve without frameworks and what problems they try to solve

Comment: True but I been coding in JS for a while and my lines of code has become huge. I researched into Jquery and it seemed to be good for shortening the code so I wanted to get head start with it.

Comment: Use domready event always. you don't have to use loop in jquery to change css or to add click event. the selector will do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

did you mean? 
Example :

```
jQuery('Button').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).css({'background':'#000','color':'#FFF','font-weight':'bold'})
        .on('click', function(evt){
        // do something
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: I have 1 question, how will the code now what its looking for, for example, there might a ID for a element called Button and there may be elements with tag name Button.

Comment: if you tag name Private "Button" you write "Button" else if html button you must write "button"

Comment: What is type seatsLayout?

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.ready` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').css({
        'background' : '#000',
        'color' : '#fff',
        'font-weight' : 'bold'
    }).on('click', function() {
        //write your click handler here
    });
});
```

this will work

Comment: He wouldn't need `$(document).ready` if his `getElementsByTagName` worked fine.

Comment: He is asking for tips. If he want to do jQuery in best way. It is best practice to use domready also I added answer to question.

Comment: Real best practice is to put the the javascript at the very end of the HTML document so all objects are already created. To tell him that you can use `$(document).ready` if the elements are not created at the point of javascript execution would be correct, but using it for no reason what-so-ever makes no sense. You might as well also wrap the whole thing in a [immediately-invoked function expression](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/05/22/function%E2%80%A6-vs-function%E2%80%A6-or-domready-vs-the-module-pattern/) to make sure there's no scoping issues if you're talking best practises.

Comment: I agree to using JS at the bottom of page before the end of body tag is a best practice. Using dom ready it will ensure that your dom is loaded and you can select any element and do any action on it

Answer (score 0):

> how I can achieve this in Jquery:

Simply

```
$("Button").each(function(){
  var button = $(this);
  button.css("background","#000");
  button.css("color ","#fff");
  button.css("font-weight","bold");
  button.click( function(){
    //your method operation   
  });
});
```

Comment: This is definitely a complete and succinct answer, don't know why they downvoted you.

Comment: @MitchKarajohn Probably someone who wondered why that 1. he keeps using `$(this)` forcing jQuery to refetch the selector and 2. he doesn't use the chaining that jQuery supports to do all of it in the same call and 3. he doesn't use an object for specifying css which would only require one `css` call rather than 3. OP specifically said he used jQuery to shorten his code, so giving him the longest possible jQuery solution seems silly. That said, *I* didn't downvote him.

Comment: I have 1 question, how will the code now what its looking for, for example, there might a ID for a element called Button and there may be elements with tag name Button.

Comment: @Henry jQuery will look for every HTML element with the tag `Button` (`$('Button')`) and iterate through each of them (`.each`) (**which is not needed - jQuery does this automatically on a collection**). If you want to use an ID, use `#Button`. If you want to use a class use `.Button`. jQuery uses very css-like selectors.

Comment: OP said himself he is a beginner; this is a fine answer for a beginner, in the sense that it's clear and easy to follow. I hardly believe OP cares for chaining and invoking the $ multiple times as much as he cares  about understanding what you are supposed to be doing there.

Comment: @h2ooooooo fair enough, but I guess this code is more relatable to his existing code.